# HTTP get request headers not setting correctly in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, http, get, http-headers

I am trying to send http get request along with headers as below

```
    var headers = {}
    headers['x-email'] = 1;
    headers['x-from'] = 1577836800;
    headers['x-to'] = 1598659200;


return this.http.get<any>(environment.apiUrl+'/User/getTrips',{headers: new HttpHeaders(headers)})
      .subscribe(data => {
        if (data == undefined) {
          this.rowData = [];
          this.errorMsg = data['Error'];
        } else {
          this.rowData = data.slice(1);
          this.gridOptions.rowData = data;
          this.gridOptions.api.refreshCells({force : true});
        }
```

When i see in network console, i could not see any headers in the request and hence am getting empty api response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try initializing the variable before using it.

```
  const httpHeaders: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
        'x-email': 1,
        'x-from': 1577836800
        'x-to': 1598659200
      });
```

and then

```
 this.http.get<any>(environment.apiUrl+'/User/getTrips',
    {headers: httpHeaders })//... code continues here
```

My initial thought is `HttpHeaders` class has a few subtleties since it is immutable. By changing the initialization this way we make sure it is using the correct type and that everything is properly initialized before invoking the `http.get`

btw this is not correct:
*if data is undefined; there is no Error property

```
 if (data == undefined) {
          this.rowData = [];
          this.errorMsg = data['Error']; /* if data is undefined; there is no Error property*/
        }
```

Comment: Thanks much. It worked. Yeah sorry, you are right, if data is undefined, there is no error property.